# C# Yield Return on Dart / Flutter Return List<String> in Loop

Tags: dart, flutter

I have the following method:

```
List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> _buildGitIgnoreTemplateItems() {
    var _dropDownMenuItems = List<DropdownMenuItem<String>>();

    _gitIgnoreTemplateNames.forEach((templateName) {
        _dropDownMenuItems.add(DropdownMenuItem(
            child: Text(templateName),
            value: templateName,
        ));
    });

    return _dropDownMenuItems;
}
```

What i am trying to achived is remove the variable `_dropDownMenuItems` something like:

```
List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> _buildGitIgnoreTemplateItems() {
    _gitIgnoreTemplateNames.forEach((templateName) {
        **yield return** DropdownMenuItem(
            child: Text(templateName),
            value: templateName,
        );
    });
}
```

You can see similar implementation in other languages like: [C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/yield)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C# is way too long ago, but it looks like [Synchronous generators](https://www.dartlang.org/articles/language/beyond-async#synchronous-generators-sync)

```
Iterable<DropdownMenuItem<String>> _buildGitIgnoreTemplateItems() sync* {
    for(var templateName in _gitIgnoreTemplateNames) {
        yield DropdownMenuItem(
            child: Text(templateName),
            value: templateName,
        );
    }
}
```

but perhaps you just want

```
_gitIgnoreTemplateNames.map((templateName) => 
    DropdownMenuItem(
      child Text(templateName), 
      value: templateName)
    ).toList()
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. I can convert to a list using `_buildGitIgnoreTemplateItems().toList()`. Thank you @Günter

Comment: Not sure though what the purpose is that you want to do it this way. Looks like what you want might be just  `_gitIgnoreTemplateNames.map((templateName) => DropdownMenuItem(child Text(templateName), value: templateName)).toList()`

Comment: The `map` method is what i was looking for. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent in dart is with `Stream` and `StreamController` for async. And `Iterable` for sync. You can create them manually or using custom function with `async*` or `sync*` keywords

```
Iterable<String> foo() sync* {
  yield "Hello";
}


Stream<String> foo() async* {
  yield "Hello";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Dart has a simpler syntax to achieve what you want:

```
List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> _buildGitIgnoreTemplateItems() {
  return _gitIgnoreTemplateNames
      .map((g) => DropdownMenuItem(
            child: Text(g),
            value: g,
          ))
      .toList();
}
```